# checking contents of a table in SQL server by Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, windows-forms-designer

I have a table named`Users`in SQL server which retains `password`,`email` and `UserID` which is the primary key.
Then in my project I have two forms,first form gets password and name of users and then if entered password and email exist in the table it connects to second form and if not it does not.
then to connect to bank I am using Entity Framework. this is my connection string:

```
   int UserID = 2;
        UsersEntities db = new UsersEntities();
        var find = db.CalUsers.Find(UserID);
        if (find.Email == txtEmail.Text && find.Password == txtPassword.Text)
        {
            SmallCalculator example = new SmallCalculator();
            example.ShowDialog();
        }
```

I know I must use `UserID` as primary key but I dont know how to write `UserID`to get all rows?now it just gets row`2`

Comment: I'm not really clear on what you are asking, but if you want all rows, drop Find(UserID) and just refer to db.CalUsers.

Comment: It's not possible to just refer to db.CalUsers, it requires a linq like Find or something

Comment: Not so.  db.CalUsers is an IEnumerable<T> .

Comment: If you are looking up a primary key you will only get one result.

Comment: so how can i check all informations in bank? it's not something weird it's just like so many other websites or programs that check user information before permission to enter to website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   int UserID = 2; // you don't actually know this value since user is not giving it to you
    UsersEntities db = new UsersEntities();

    //hopefully email address has a unique constraint:
    var find = db.CalUsers.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Email == txtEmail.Text.Trim());

    if(find == null) return; //do something else

    if (find.Email == txtEmail.Text && find.Password == txtPassword.Text)
    {
        SmallCalculator example = new SmallCalculator();
        example.ShowDialog();
    }
```